# Getting "cannot convert from TriggerBuilder<Trigger> to Trigger" while running simple Quratz tutorial program

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I am new to java Quartz scheduling and have been trying to run a simple quartz program from a youtube tutorial.

This is the code I tried :

```
public class drive1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {              
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(Job.class).build();     
        Trigger trigger =  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").startNow();        
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();        
        scheduler.start();      
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);      
    }
}
```

This keeps on giving me compilation error at line 4 : 
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from TriggerBuilder<Trigger> to Trigger`

So I tried explicitly type casting at line 4 : 
`Trigger trigger =  (Trigger)TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").startNow();`

This removed the compilation error but now I am getting a run time exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.TriggerBuilder cannot be cast to org.quartz.Trigger
    at sd.moc.drive1.main(drive1.java:18)
```

Could someone please help me out.
I know this is a noob questions, but I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to 'build' the trigger. So you would need to change

```
Trigger trigger =  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").startNow();
```

to

```
Trigger trigger =  TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("SimpleTrigger").startNow().build();
```

Comment: awesome, that seems to solve the problem...but any clue why .startNow(); was not working, as I see ".startNow();" aslo returns "TriggerBuilder<T>" which again extends Trigger ?

Comment: TriggerBuilder does not extend Trigger itself, it is a generic type that produces objects that extend Triggers.